# Problems running pig script in mapreduce mode

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have got a running hadoop (2.6.0) cluster with 6 nodes (master node included) and want to run a pig (0.14.0) script in mapreduce mode. The script is running with no errors, but unfortunately it seems that it is only running on the master node. During my research I tried some changes to the hadoop config files with no success.

Can you help me figure out how to get pig working on the whole cluster?

Here are some information:

**Configuration on every node:**

General:

*/etc/hosts*

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.101.3   master
192.168.101.4   node1
192.168.101.5   node2
192.168.101.6   node3
192.168.101.7   node4
192.168.101.8   node5
```

Hadoop:

*yarn-site.xml*

```
<configuration>
<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
        <property>
                <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
                <value>master</value>
                <description>...</description>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
                <value>master:8025</value>
                <description>...</description>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
                <value>master:8030</value>
                <description>...</description>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
                <value>master:8050</value>
                <description>...</description>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
                <value>master:8041</value>
                <description>...</description>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux_services</name>
                <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux_services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
                <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>yarn.log.server.url</name>
                <value>master:19888/jobhistory/logs/</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

*core-site.xml*

```
<configuration>
        <property>
                <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
                <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
                <description>A base for other temporary dictionaries.</description>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
                <value>hdfs://master:9000/</value>
                <description>...</description>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

*mapred-site.xml*

```
<configuration>
        <property>
                <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.address</name>
                <value>master:54311</value>
                <description>...</description>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>mapred.framework.name</name>
                <value>yarn</value>
                <final>true</final>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
                <value>master:10020</value>
                <description>...</description>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name>
                <value>master:19888</value>
                <description>...</description>
        </property>

</configuration>
```

**pig output:**

```
15/01/09 13:12:54 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Trying ExecType : LOCAL
15/01/09 13:12:54 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Trying ExecType : MAPREDUCE
15/01/09 13:12:54 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Picked MAPREDUCE as the ExecType
2015-01-09 13:12:54,845 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig version 0.14.0 (r1640057) compiled Nov 16 2014, 18:02:05
2015-01-09 13:12:54,845 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to: /home/hduser/pig_1420805574843.log
2015-01-09 13:12:56,450 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.Utils - Default bootup file /home/hduser/.pigbootup not found
2015-01-09 13:12:56,876 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
2015-01-09 13:12:56,886 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2015-01-09 13:12:56,886 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to hadoop file system at: hdfs://master:9000/
2015-01-09 13:12:58,146 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to map-reduce job tracker at: master:54311
2015-01-09 13:12:59,195 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2015-01-09 13:12:59,418 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2015-01-09 13:12:59,598 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2015-01-09 13:13:00,496 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the script: FILTER,UNION
2015-01-09 13:13:00,618 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2015-01-09 13:13:00,634 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleBackend - Key [pig.schematuple] was not set... will not generate code.
2015-01-09 13:13:00,713 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanOptimizer - {RULES_ENABLED=[AddForEach, ColumnMapKeyPrune, ConstantCalculator, GroupByConstParallelSetter, LimitOptimizer, LoadTypeCastInserter, MergeFilter, MergeForEach, PartitionFilterOptimizer, PredicatePushdownOptimizer, PushDownForEachFlatten, PushUpFilter, SplitFilter, StreamTypeCastInserter]}
2015-01-09 13:13:00,987 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false
2015-01-09 13:13:01,037 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size before optimization: 1
2015-01-09 13:13:01,038 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size after optimization: 1
2015-01-09 13:13:01,079 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2015-01-09 13:13:01,103 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
2015-01-09 13:13:01,105 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
2015-01-09 13:13:01,149 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRScriptState - Pig script settings are added to the job
2015-01-09 13:13:01,161 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent
2015-01-09 13:13:01,161 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3
2015-01-09 13:13:01,161 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.output.compress is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress
2015-01-09 13:13:01,167 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - This job cannot be converted run in-process
2015-01-09 13:13:19,222 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/home/hduser/pig-0.14.0/pig-0.14.0-core-h2.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp-1277984423/tmp-918732110/pig-0.14.0-core-h2.jar
2015-01-09 13:13:20,063 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/home/hduser/pig-0.14.0/lib/automaton-1.11-8.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp-1277984423/tmp883771618/automaton-1.11-8.jar
2015-01-09 13:13:20,621 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/home/hduser/pig-0.14.0/lib/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp-1277984423/tmp-1372558595/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar
2015-01-09 13:13:26,600 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp-1277984423/tmp-1556176302/guava-11.0.2.jar
2015-01-09 13:13:29,300 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/home/hduser/pig-0.14.0/lib/joda-time-2.1.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp-1277984423/tmp145012374/joda-time-2.1.jar
2015-01-09 13:13:29,718 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Setting up single store job
2015-01-09 13:13:29,736 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Key [pig.schematuple] is false, will not generate code.
2015-01-09 13:13:29,736 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Starting process to move generated code to distributed cacche
2015-01-09 13:13:29,736 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Setting key [pig.schematuple.classes] with classes to deserialize []
2015-01-09 13:13:29,840 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 1 map-reduce job(s) waiting for submission.
2015-01-09 13:13:29,841 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker.http.address is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.http.address
2015-01-09 13:13:30,191 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2015-01-09 13:13:30,384 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2015-01-09 13:13:30,785 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
2015-01-09 13:13:30,949 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 1
2015-01-09 13:13:30,949 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths to process : 1
2015-01-09 13:13:31,250 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths (combined) to process : 52
2015-01-09 13:13:31,309 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 1
2015-01-09 13:13:31,309 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths to process : 1
2015-01-09 13:13:31,355 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths (combined) to process : 24
2015-01-09 13:13:31,378 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 1
2015-01-09 13:13:31,379 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths to process : 1
2015-01-09 13:13:31,394 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths (combined) to process : 6
2015-01-09 13:13:31,587 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - number of splits:82
2015-01-09 13:13:31,706 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2015-01-09 13:13:32,475 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - Submitting tokens for job: job_local647507189_0001
2015-01-09 13:13:33,628 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1420805612754/pig-0.14.0-core-h2.jar <- /home/hduser/pig-0.14.0-core-h2.jar
2015-01-09 13:13:33,758 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - Localized hdfs://master:9000/tmp/temp-1277984423/tmp-918732110/pig-0.14.0-core-h2.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1420805612754/pig-0.14.0-core-h2.jar
2015-01-09 13:13:33,759 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1420805612755/automaton-1.11-8.jar <- /home/hduser/automaton-1.11-8.jar
2015-01-09 13:13:33,770 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - Localized hdfs://master:9000/tmp/temp-1277984423/tmp883771618/automaton-1.11-8.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1420805612755/automaton-1.11-8.jar
2015-01-09 13:13:33,772 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1420805612756/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar <- /home/hduser/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar
2015-01-09 13:13:33,781 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - Localized hdfs://master:9000/tmp/temp-1277984423/tmp-1372558595/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1420805612756/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar
2015-01-09 13:15:54,534 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp206201348/tmp-1481268210/guava-11.0.2.jar
2015-01-09 13:15:56,233 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Added jar file:/home/hduser/pig-0.14.0/lib/joda-time-2.1.jar to DistributedCache through /tmp/temp206201348/tmp-1921418840/joda-time-2.1.jar
2015-01-09 13:15:56,340 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Setting up single store job
2015-01-09 13:15:56,366 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Key [pig.schematuple] is false, will not generate code.
2015-01-09 13:15:56,367 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Starting process to move generated code to distributed cacche
2015-01-09 13:15:56,368 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Setting key [pig.schematuple.classes] with classes to deserialize []
2015-01-09 13:15:56,483 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 1 map-reduce job(s) waiting for submission.
2015-01-09 13:15:56,486 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker.http.address is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.http.address
2015-01-09 13:15:56,505 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2015-01-09 13:15:56,582 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2015-01-09 13:15:56,695 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
2015-01-09 13:15:57,070 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 1
2015-01-09 13:15:57,070 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths to process : 1
2015-01-09 13:15:57,197 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths (combined) to process : 52
2015-01-09 13:15:57,227 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 1
2015-01-09 13:15:57,228 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths to process : 1
2015-01-09 13:15:57,263 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths (combined) to process : 24
2015-01-09 13:15:57,289 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 1
2015-01-09 13:15:57,289 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths to process : 1
2015-01-09 13:15:57,306 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths (combined) to process : 6
2015-01-09 13:15:57,393 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - number of splits:82
2015-01-09 13:15:57,416 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2015-01-09 13:15:57,791 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - Submitting tokens for job: job_local561414911_0001
2015-01-09 13:15:58,741 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1420805758017/pig-0.14.0-core-h2.jar <- /home/hduser/pig-0.14.0-core-h2.jar
2015-01-09 13:15:58,755 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - Localized hdfs://master:9000/tmp/temp206201348/tmp1912320441/pig-0.14.0-core-h2.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1420805758017/pig-0.14.0-core-h2.jar
2015-01-09 13:15:58,757 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1420805758018/automaton-1.11-8.jar <- /home/hduser/automaton-1.11-8.jar
2015-01-09 13:15:58,766 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - Localized hdfs://master:9000/tmp/temp206201348/tmp-886499198/automaton-1.11-8.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1420805758018/automaton-1.11-8.jar
2015-01-09 13:15:58,768 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1420805758019/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar <- /home/hduser/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar
2015-01-09 13:15:58,778 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - Localized hdfs://master:9000/tmp/temp206201348/tmp1437387446/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1420805758019/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar
2015-01-09 13:15:58,779 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1420805758020/guava-11.0.2.jar <- /home/hduser/guava-11.0.2.jar
2015-01-09 13:15:58,786 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - Localized hdfs://master:9000/tmp/temp206201348/tmp-1481268210/guava-11.0.2.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1420805758020/guava-11.0.2.jar
2015-01-09 13:15:58,787 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1420805758021/joda-time-2.1.jar <- /home/hduser/joda-time-2.1.jar
2015-01-09 13:15:58,795 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - Localized hdfs://master:9000/tmp/temp206201348/tmp-1921418840/joda-time-2.1.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1420805758021/joda-time-2.1.jar
2015-01-09 13:15:58,953 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1420805758017/pig-0.14.0-core-h2.jar
2015-01-09 13:15:58,954 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1420805758018/automaton-1.11-8.jar
2015-01-09 13:15:58,955 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1420805758019/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar
2015-01-09 13:15:58,955 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1420805758020/guava-11.0.2.jar
2015-01-09 13:15:58,955 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager - file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1420805758021/joda-time-2.1.jar
2015-01-09 13:15:58,970 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job - The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
2015-01-09 13:15:58,973 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - HadoopJobId: job_local561414911_0001
2015-01-09 13:15:58,973 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Processing aliases records_infobox,records_mappingbased,records_person,records_union,result_filter
2015-01-09 13:15:58,973 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - detailed locations: M: records_person[10,17],records_person[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],records_union[13,16],records_infobox[6,18],records_infobox[-1,-1],result_filter[16,16],records_mappingbased[8,23],records_mappingbased[-1,-1],null[-1,-1] C:  R: 
2015-01-09 13:15:58,990 [Thread-19] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - OutputCommitter set in config null
2015-01-09 13:15:58,991 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 0% complete
2015-01-09 13:15:58,994 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Running jobs are [job_local561414911_0001]
2015-01-09 13:15:59,067 [Thread-19] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent
2015-01-09 13:15:59,069 [Thread-19] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2015-01-09 13:15:59,069 [Thread-19] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
2015-01-09 13:15:59,094 [Thread-19] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - OutputCommitter is org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputCommitter
2015-01-09 13:15:59,257 [Thread-19] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - Waiting for map tasks
2015-01-09 13:15:59,258 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - Starting task: attempt_local561414911_0001_m_000000_0
2015-01-09 13:15:59,459 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task -  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
2015-01-09 13:15:59,470 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask - Processing split: Number of splits :1
Total Length = 134217728
Input split[0]:
   Length = 134217728
   ClassName: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit
   Locations:

-----------------------

2015-01-09 13:15:59,522 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigRecordReader - Current split being processed hdfs://master:9000/wiki/infobox_properties_en.nt:0+134217728
2015-01-09 13:15:59,662 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleBackend - Key [pig.schematuple] was not set... will not generate code.
2015-01-09 13:15:59,743 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigMapOnly$Map - Aliases being processed per job phase (AliasName[line,offset]): M: records_person[10,17],records_person[-1,-1],null[-1,-1],records_union[13,16],records_infobox[6,18],records_infobox[-1,-1],result_filter[16,16],records_mappingbased[8,23],records_mappingbased[-1,-1],null[-1,-1] C:  R: 
2015-01-09 13:15:59,798 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigHadoopLogger - org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POProject(ACCESSING_NON_EXISTENT_FIELD): Attempt to access field which was not found in the input
2015-01-09 13:15:59,815 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigHadoopLogger - org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POProject(ACCESSING_NON_EXISTENT_FIELD): Attempt to access field which was not found in the input
2015-01-09 13:16:05,578 [communication thread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - map > map
2015-01-09 13:16:08,582 [communication thread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - map > map
2015-01-09 13:16:10,209 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - map > map
2015-01-09 13:16:10,699 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task - Task:attempt_local561414911_0001_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of committing
2015-01-09 13:16:10,714 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - map > map
2015-01-09 13:16:10,714 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task - Task attempt_local561414911_0001_m_000000_0 is allowed to commit now
2015-01-09 13:16:10,849 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter - Saved output of task 'attempt_local561414911_0001_m_000000_0' to hdfs://master:9000/tmp/temp206201348/tmp-1297558267/_temporary/0/task_local561414911_0001_m_000000
2015-01-09 13:16:10,854 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - map
2015-01-09 13:16:10,854 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task - Task 'attempt_local561414911_0001_m_000000_0' done.
2015-01-09 13:16:10,855 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - Finishing task: attempt_local561414911_0001_m_000000_0
2015-01-09 13:16:10,855 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - Starting task: attempt_local561414911_0001_m_000001_0
2015-01-09 13:16:10,877 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task -  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
2015-01-09 13:16:10,883 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask - Processing split: Number of splits :1
....
```

Comment: check the web interface whether all nodes are up and running (master-ip:50070 and master-ip:8088). did you start all nodes using `$HADOOPHOME/sbin/start-dfs.sh` and `$HADOOPHOME/sbin/start-yarn.sh` ? How big is the data?

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. My pig job is picking up the HDFS files but using LocalJobRunner in mapreduce mode. Let me know if you get any solution.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I couldn't figure out my problem. So I reconfigured my whole cluster from scratch. And it worked. I know this is not a satisfying solution, but I can't tell what exactly went wrong. Most probably it was something wrong in the hadoop/hosts configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, but with different `mapred-site.xml`, but nonetheless I think the problem is there.

`Yarn` is the next version of `MR`, that's why we need the following section in the file to make sure it is used with older programs:

```
    <property>
            <name>mapred.framework.name</name>
            <value>yarn</value>
            <final>true</final>
    </property>
```

However, assuming you use `Yarn`, you don't have `Jobtracker`, since it was replaced by `ResourceManager` in some sense (actually, it was a complete re-design. You can read about it in http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/11/migrating-to-mapreduce-2-on-yarn-for-operators/ )

So, you need to **erase** the following lines:

```
    <property>
            <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.address</name>
            <value>master:54311</value>
            <description>...</description>
    </property>
```

from the file, and pig will be good to go.

(There is a relevant answer discussing this change in
[Why there is a mapreduce.jobtracker.address configuration on YARN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29680155/why-there-is-a-mapreduce-jobtracker-address-configuration-on-yarn))

Answer (score 0):

According to logs you post here your job is running in Local system([Local Job Runner])

There is one property in Pig called as `pig.auto.local.enabled` by default it comes as true for performance, it means if your data size is less then the size set in property `pig.auto.local.input.maxbytes` which is 1 GB by default pig will not execute in cluster(Yarn UI will also not show application for the job also) instead it will be executed in the node where it is launched. Both the properties you can set in pig.properties file.