# Why there is a mapreduce.jobtracker.address configuration on YARN?

Tags: xml, hadoop, mapreduce, jobs, hadoop-yarn

YARN is the Hadoop second generation that not use the jobtracker daemon anymore, and substitute it with resource manager. But why, on mapred-site.xml hadoop 2 there is an mapreduce.jobtracker.address property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct. In YARN, jobtracker no longer exists. So as part of client configuration you don't have to to specify the property `mapreduce.jobtracker.address`. In YARN, you should specify the property `mapreduce.framework.name` to `yarn` in the  config file. Instead of setting up mapreduce.jotracker.address, you need to specify `yarn.resourcemanager.address`.

Comment: In stack overflow, if you find an answer useful, You need to accept the answer by clicking tick options at the left side of the answer. If you are doing so, the answers will be useful for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

setting yarn.resourcemanager.address is not mandatory:

refer following link which explains migration from MR1 to MR2

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-4-x/topics/cdh_ig_mapreduce_to_yarn_migrate.html